# Canon MG-5550 printer doesn't install with Canon packages on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, printing, canon

(Just for sharing because I found the solution.)

## Context

Canon provides precompiled debian 32-bit and 64-bit printer drivers for many of their printers, including MG-5550.
On Xubuntu 16.04, installing `cnijfilter-mg5500series` fails with:

```
lpadmin: Unable to copy PPD file.
```

## Search before you post

- `man lpadmin`, etc does not provide a clue.
- `strace` does not even show `lpadmin` trying to open a `ppd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## (1) Find root cause

Tracing `cupsd` process shows that it finds PPD okay, but also shows this:

```
stat("/usr/lib/cups/daemon/cups-driverd", 0x7ffde15f8ba0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

A search on the file mentioned...

```
apt-file find /usr/lib/cups/daemon/cups-driverd
```

... (alternative: go to [Ubuntu package content search -- /usr/lib/cups/daemon/cups-driverd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fusr%2Flib%2Fcups%2Fdaemon%2Fcups-driverd&mode=&suite=xenial&arch=any) returns:

```
cups: /usr/lib/cups/daemon/cups-driverd
```

And indeed several CUPS-related packages are installed but not `cups`.

## (2) Fix root cause

```
apt-get install cups
```

I purged half-installed printer and reinstalled CANON packages.

## (3) Profit!

Printer works.