# Photo printing app

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I have a canon Pixma MG5220 printer.Some features work on Linux 16.04,but the photo printing features only seem to work properly with the actual Canon program.This was true even when I ran windows.(no dual boot here).Is there a Linux program that can control such things as paper size,paper type-glossy,matt,etc?As far as I know there are no Linux drivers for this model.Some other versions of Pixma are supported,but not this one.

Comment: There are Linux drivers otherwise it wouldn't be detected.  There could be better ones though as the most upvoted answer here suggests: http://askubuntu.com/questions/168089/how-do-i-install-my-new-canon-mg5250-printer-mg5200-series . But what you're asking is already available with your current driver. System Settings > Printers. Right-click and select Properties.

Comment: May also be relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/821686/canon-mg-5550-printer-doesnt-install-with-canon-packages-on-xubuntu-16-04